# MonoTouch App on Latest Alpha 4.1.0 (build 45)

Tags: xamarin.ios

yesterday i have updated to the latest version of xamarin.ios, the problem i'm experiencing is that existing apps, are not working anymore with datasources, for example i have a simple tableview with my custom datasource, everything run fine with no exception, but when it is executed GetCell or RowsInSection for example are not called.
Do you have any idea why? there is maybe some change to apply on my code to make it working?

Comment: it's Alpha software, if you find a problem you should report it to Xamarin - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have found it, on older version the UITableViewDataSource worked fine without it, just adding this override fixed it.

```
public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
{
    return 1;
}
```